# Пустой выбор в Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию в `Spinner` не было выбрано ничего и вместо текста было пустое поле, которое заполняется уже при выборе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том что для спиннера нельзя установить значение null по умолчанию при старте активности/фрагмента. Этот виджет будет автоматически выбирать значение которое стоит первым в списке. У меня была такая-же проблема, и я смог ее решить добавив дополнительную запись в массив названий пунктов:

```
private String[] items = { "Your items", "Item_1", "Item_2", "Item_3" };
```

либо второй вариант решения попался мне в сети. Сделать свой адаптер для спиннера:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int textViewResourceId;
    private String[] objects;
    public static boolean flag = false;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.objects = objects;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = View.inflate(context, textViewResourceId, null);
        if (flag != false) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
            tv.setText(objects[position]);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

и вот подключение:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            // Set adapter flag that something has been chosen  
            CustomAdapter.flag = true;  
        }
    });
```

лично я второй вариант не пробовал, а остановился на первом так как он простой и не требует много телодвижений. Надеюсь один из этих способов решения поможет вам. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: рад что у вас все получилось :)